CSS Media Query Not Capturing Specific Screen Size (384x730)
I'm working on a responsive design for a project and I'm trying to target specific screen sizes using media queries. However, my current media query doesn't seem to be capturing a screen size of 384x730 with a device pixel ratio of 2.
Here’s the CSS media query I'm currently using:
@media only screen 
  and (max-width: 375px) 
  and (max-height: 667px)
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  
  /* Add your styles here */
  .home-container {
    width:10% !important;
  }
  .hero-content {
    align-self: unset !important; /* or initial */

  }
  .hero-action {
    width: unset !important;
  }
}
@media only screen 
  and (max-width: 414px) 
  and (max-height: 896px)
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  
  /* Add your styles here */
  .home-container {
    width:10% !important;
  }
  .hero-content {
    align-self: unset !important; /* or initial */

  }
  .hero-action {
    width: unset !important;
  }
}
@media only screen 
  and (max-width: 384px) 
  and (max-height: 730px)
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  
  /* Add your styles here */
  .home-container {
    width:10% !important;
  }
  .hero-content {
    align-self: unset !important; /* or initial */

  }
  .hero-action {
    width: unset !important;
    }
    }


Issue:
This media query is not applying the styles to a device with a screen size of 384x730, but I was expecting it to. I believe the issue might be with the max-height, but I'm not entirely sure. I tried adjusting the max-height to 730px, but it still doesn't seem to capture the screen.
My Goal:
I want this media query to apply to devices with a screen size of 384px width and 730px height with a device pixel ratio of 2.

Have you verified that the viewport actually is as large as you think? (You're aware that it doesn't have to match the actual physical screen dimensions, right?)

FYI, you appear to be applying the exact formatting across all three of those media queries there - if that is intentional, you should be able to write this as one, using a comma as an "or", https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-css-media-queries/#aa-or

Any screen with those dimensions also fits the second media query. Are you certain the !importants there aren’t ‘sticking’? Have you used your browser devtools to check?

Thanks, everyone. I'll check everything and get back to you if it works
